# ERROR: SvtAv1Enc not found using pkg-config

Tags: linux, plugins, ffmpeg, build

I am trying to compile FFmpeg with SVT-AV1 codec, following instructions from here: https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-AV1/tree/master/ffmpeg_plugin

Everything goes well, but when I try to run

```
./configure --enable-libsvtav1
```

I am getting

```
ERROR: SvtAv1Enc not found using pkg-config

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

The content of the ffbuild/config.log: https://pastebin.com/euPriFAp

There is an exact issue on the github: https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-AV1/issues/35, but is closed as solved.

I have tried both on my Mac and in the Docker container with Ubuntu 18.04, but getting the same result.

Could anyone please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was in the lack of required libraries. Please find the complete installation instruction below.

Installing packages required for compiling:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

```
sudo apt-get install \
  autoconf \
  automake \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git-core \
  libass-dev \
  libfreetype6-dev \
  libsdl2-dev \
  libtool \
  libva-dev \
  libvdpau-dev \
  libvorbis-dev \
  libxcb1-dev \
  libxcb-shm0-dev \
  libxcb-xfixes0-dev \
  pkg-config \
  texinfo \
  wget \
  zlib1g-dev
```

Installing assemblers used by some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install nasm
sudo apt-get install yasm
```

Build and install SVT-AV1:

```
git clone --depth=1 https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1.git
cd SVT-AV1
cd Build
cmake .. -G"Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
make -j $(nproc)
sudo make install
```

Apply SVT-AV1 plugin and enable libsvtav1 to FFmpeg:

```
cd ~
git clone -b release/4.2 --depth=1 https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH+=":/usr/local/lib"
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH+=":/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
git apply ../SVT-AV1/ffmpeg_plugin/0001-Add-ability-for-ffmpeg-to-run-svt-av1.patch
./configure --enable-libsvtav1
```

(**Note**: if you want other codecs to be supported please add the required flags to the `./configure` command)

Build FFmpeg:

```
make
make install
hash -r
source ~/.profile
```

Now you should have `ffmpeg` command working and have svt-av1 in encoders list:

```
ffmpeg -encoders
```

```
...
V..... libsvt_av1           SVT-AV1(Scalable Video Technology for AV1) encoder (codec av1)
...
```

I used next docs a reference:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu
- https://github.com/OpenVisualCloud/SVT-AV1/tree/master/ffmpeg_plugin

Comment: It seems the library has moved to https://gitlab.com/AOMediaCodec/SVT-AV1

Comment: Additionally there's no 0001-Add-ability-for-ffmpeg-to-run-svt-av1.patch any more, and seems not to be needed any more.

Comment: All earlier comments are true, except that I still get the same error as OP.